# SelectedValue of ComboBox is not of the type I expect

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, .net-4.8

Consider a complex object defined by an interface `IMyInterface`. I have a collection of those objects which I want to present in a `ComboBox` to select a specific instance:

```
IEnumerable<IMyInterface> myCollection = GetCollectionFromWhereverItOriginates();
cmb_MyBox.DataSource = myCollection.Select(x => new {Display = x.Name, Value = x}).ToList();
cmb_MyBox.DisplayMember = "Display";
cmb_MyBox.ValueMember = "Value";
```

At first, this yields the desired result. What is displayed to the user is exactly what I specified. But when I want to retrieve the actual selected object/value things start to fall apart.

```
private void cmb_MyBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IMyInterface theSelectedObject = (IMyInterface)cmb_MyBox.SelectedValue; //Things fall apart
    DoSomethingAwesome(theSelectedObject);
}
```

I get a `InvalidCastException`, because the anonymous type cannot be cast to `IMyInterface`. Which is odd. Thinking that, maybe, this has to do with anonymous types, I create an intermediate layer:

```
class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string DisplayText {get; set;}
    public IMyObject TheValue {get; set;} //Chose "TheValue" on purpose to avoid any collisions with the reserved name "value" (No capitals!)
}

cmb_MyBox.DataSource = myCollection.Select(x => new ComboBoxItem() {Display = x.Name, TheValue = x}).ToList();
```

This changes things, the exception remains, but now it tells me, that `ComboBoxItem` cannot be cast to `IMyInterface`.

If I understand the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember?view=netframework-4.8.1) correctly (which I obviously don't), then I would expect the following behaviour:

- The anonymous Type in the `DataSource` has two properties: `Display` (which is of type `string`, because `IMyInterface.Name` is defined as a `string`) and `Value` (which is of type `IMyInterface`, because the items in the collection I create everything from is of type `IMyInterface`)
- Analogous the `ComboBoxItem` has two properties of these types
- Setting `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` point to the *properties of the object in the datasource*, or as the documentation puts it:

> Gets or sets the path of the property to use as the actual value for the items in the ListControl.

- `SelectedValue` for the `ComboBox` is defined as an `object` and thus needs casting to the concrete type I need to retrieve it. Again, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue?view=netframework-4.8.1) indicates, that `SelectedValue` is the *property of the DataSource-object rather than the DataSource-object itself*

> Gets or sets the value of the member property specified by the ValueMember property.

The compiler is obviously of a different opinion and I would like to understand

1. Why that is?
2. What I am missing?
3. How I can achieve my desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the order I did things in.

Setting the member-properties first and *then* setting the DataSource gives the expected behaviour. Even with the anonymous type.

The question that remains is: Why is that not documented? The [example given](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember?view=netframework-4.8.1#examples) also first sets the DataSource and then the member-properties. But in the example all properties are strings, so that maybe skews the behaviour towards "it will work somehow".

Answer (score 0):

If you have an interface

```cs
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string Display { get; set; }
    int Value { get; set; }
}
```

and you assign

```cs
cmb_MyBox.DataSource = <some collection of `IMyInterface`>;
cmb_MyBox.DisplayMember = "Display";
cmb_MyBox.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Then

- `SelectedValue` is of type `int`
- `SelectedItem` is of type `IMyInterface`

Comment: Well yes, that is what I expect, but apparently it is not :)

Comment: You are writing `(IMyInterface)cmb_MyBox.SelectedValue;` instead of `(IMyInterface)cmb_MyBox.SelectedItem;`. The collection assigned to the data source is a `List<IMyInterface>`. So `SelectedItem` is of type `IMyInterface`, not `SelectedValue`. Please, show us the declaration of the interface. Also you claim that the interface has a `Name` property but you don't say `cmb_MyBox.DisplayMember = "Name";`. Very confusing.

Comment: Create a small demo application and test both variants (DataSource set before and after setting the ValueMember). You will see (if you do a cmb_MyBox.SelectedValue.GetType() in the immediate window), that the type is different between the two.

Comment: The SelectedValue maps to the underlying ListControl. I chose this because the similarity between ValueMember and SelectedValue made me think it was appropriate. The declaration of the interface is not relevant. But if I want the whole object as a Value from the ComboBox and not only one property I would need to have a "Self"-property defined in the interface, which I don't have, thus I used the anonymous type.

Comment: But I just figured out, that I do not necessarily need to specify both the display and the value member. If I can point directly to a property I can just set the display member accordingly. If however I need a separate display string that does not map to a specific property I have to get more creative.

Comment: `SelectedItem` is always the whole object. You can set `DisplayMember = "Name"` if the object has a `Name` property to be displayed or override `ToString()` to display anything you want and don't set `DisplayMember` at all.